# Pulling Trello card members into google sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

I'm sure this is insanely simple but I've been bashing my head against it on and off for a week now and getting nowhere.
I'm pulling details of Trello cards into a google sheet with the ultimate aim of sending an email to the members of any Trello card from a given list that's exceeded a certain number of days since the last activity.

I'm able to get the cards and relevant fields from Trello using

```
//get all cards from board   
var url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/<board id>/cards?filter=open&fields=name,idList,url,dateLastActivity,idMembers,idLabels&key=<key>&token=<token>";

var get = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

and then to parse the return

```
//parse JSON 
var dataSet = JSON.parse(get);
```

The problem I've encountered is that where there's more than one member of a card the IDs are returned as a comma seperarated list within a sub-array like this

```
{idMembers=[member_id, member_id, member_id], idLabels=[label_id], name=card_name, dateLastActivity=date, id=card_id, idList=list_id, url=https://trello.com/c/XXxxxXXxx/blahblahblahblahblahblah}
```

Looping through parsed JSON and pushing the output to a new array all the member IDs are still all together for each card but when they're passed to the spreadsheet only the first member is making the trip.
Code below

```
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
data = dataSet[i];

rows.push([data.id, 
           data.name,
           data.idList,
           data.dateLastActivity,
           data.idMembers,
           data.idLabels,
           data.url,              
          ]);
}

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
sheet.getRange(2,1,last_row,last_column).clear();  
dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 7);
dataRange.setValues(rows);
```

I've tried looping through the array again to seperate out the member IDs

```
for(j = 0; j < data.idMembers.length; j++) {
```

but that hasn't helped and I'm not sure it's even along the right lines to a solution. I'm not even sure the problem's in the code and not the google sheet's handling of comma separated values.

In the spreadsheet I don't much care (at the moment) whether I get repeated cards with a single member ID on each, an additional column for each member ID or all the member IDs together in a single cell I just want all the member IDs so I can hassle them to deal with their abandoned cards clogging up my lists.

Any and all suggestions gratefully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, using [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp):

```
rows.push([data.id, 
           data.name,
           data.idList,
           data.dateLastActivity,
           data.idMembers.join(),
           data.idLabels,
           data.url,              
          ]);
```

That worked for me, gives list of members, devided by comma:
5467844a...,52cd1e6d27...,55bf2a090...